# Terminate jquery ajax request based on beforeSend event result

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to terminate ajax execution, based on beforeSend result ?

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: check,
});

function check() {
    if(success) { /* break ajax execution */ }
    else { /* continue */ }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop $.ajax on beforeSend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507079/stop-ajax-on-beforesend) Out of votes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that answer can be found here: [Stop $.ajax on beforeSend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507079/stop-ajax-on-beforesend). It should look like below:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: check,
});

function check(xhr) {
    if(success) { xhr.abort(); }
    else { /* continue */ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the abort() method:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({     
    type: "POST",     
    url: "test",     
    data: "thedata",     
    success: function(msg){        alert( "Back again: " + msg );     } });  

//kill the request... try these on beforeSend
xhr.abort()
```

Answer (score -1):

Just place it inside a function:

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function() {
      check();  
    },
});
```