# jQuery ajax beforeSend return false doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've put together pieces of codes online to do a ajax file upload. I am able to get the code to work, my php file is able to receive the files and upload it in tmp folder.

My problem, however, is that when i use the beforeSend in the ajax call to check the file, the error is called, **but "return false" doesn't stop the ajax call**. The Ajax is still submitted calling the PHP script.

I want the file check to be done on client side (of course PHP side will do once more), and stop if it doesn't match my requirement.

This is a avatar upload function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$('#profileupload').on('change',function(e) {

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('action', 'upload_profile_image');
    formData.append('nonce', 'nonce');
    // Main magic with files here
    formData.append('image', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);

    alert('here');

    console.log(formData);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxurl',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formData,
        beforeSend: beforeSubmit(),
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (d) {
            console.log(d);
        }

    });


function beforeSubmit(){
    //check whether client browser fully supports all File API
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob)
    {
        var fsize = $('#profileupload')[0].files[0].size; //get file size
        var ftype = $('#profileupload')[0].files[0].type; // get file type
        //allow file types
        switch(ftype)
        {
            case 'image/jpeg':
                break;
            default:
                $("#output").html("<b>"+ftype+"</b> Unsupported file type!");
                console.log('false upload');
                return false
        }

        //Allowed file size is less than 5 MB (1048576 = 1 mb)
        if(fsize>5242880)
        {
            alert("<b>"+fsize +"</b> Too big file! <br />File is too big, it should be less than 5 MB.");
            console.log('false upload');
            return false
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Error for older unsupported browsers that doesn't support HTML5 File API
        alert("Please upgrade your browser, because your current browser lacks some new features we need!");
        return false
    }

}
});
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507079/stop-ajax-on-beforesend

Comment: `beforeSend: beforeSubmit,` - don't invoke the function ie `beforeSubmit(),` - In your case you are directly invoking `beforesubmit` and is passing the value returned by it as the `beforesend` value

Comment: oh @ArunPJohny Thank you i didn't see that mistake! it works now! put it in a reply please!