# Stop Navigating to other page while error message displayed in the screen on jquery Datatable Serverside processing

Tags: c#, datatables, asp.net-mvc-5

I have implemented Serverside processing for the jquery datatable. 
There is a functionality which is working fine for the "ClientSide Processing" but not working when implemented using "Serverside Processing".

> My issue is, while navigating from one page to another page in the
>   jquery datatable, if any changes exists(in textbox/dropdown in any
>   cell), then display error message and don't navigate to the next page.

**I am able to achieve this above scenario, using client side. But unable to do in server side.**

In client side i have implemented like this

```
(document).ready(function () {
        var isSuperUser = '@isUserSuperAdmin';
        var oTable = $('#tblnotreportingdetails').dataTable(
           {
               dom: 'Bfrtip',
               oLanguage: {
                   sSearch: '<i class="fa fa-search">&nbsp; </i>'
               },                  
               iDisplayLength: 7,
               buttons: [
               {
                   extend: 'copy',
                   text: '<i class="fa fa-files-o fa-2x" style="color: green;"></i>',
                   titleAttr: 'Copy',
                   exportOptions: {
                       columns: "thead th:not(.noExport)"
                   }
               },
               {
                   extend: 'excel',
                   text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o fa-2x" style="color: green;"></i>',
                   titleAttr: 'Excel',
                   exportOptions: {
                       columns: "thead th:not(.noExport)"
                   }
               },
               {
                   extend: 'csv',
                   text: '<i class="fa fa-file-text-o fa-2x" style="color: green;"></i>',
                   titleAttr: 'CSV',
                   exportOptions: {
                       columns: "thead th:not(.noExport)"
                   }
               },
               {
                   extend: 'pdf',
                   text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-2x" style="color: green;"></i>',
                   titleAttr: 'PDF',
                   exportOptions: {
                       columns: "thead th:not(.noExport)"
                   }
               },
               {
                   extend: 'print',
                   text: '<i class="fa fa-print fa-2x" style="color: green;"></i>',
                   titleAttr: 'Print',
                   exportOptions: {
                       columns: "thead th:not(.noExport)"
                   }
               }]
           });

        //Function to alert the user to save information on navigating to the next page through Pagination
        $('#tblnotreportingdetails').on('page.dt', function () {
            var selectedReasonKeyArr = [];
            //Getting the current page visible rows (10 rows/20 rows/50 rows/100 rows - default is 10 rows)
            var rows = $("#tblnotreportingdetails tbody tr");
            for (var index = 0; index < rows.length; index++) {
                //Getting each row
                var singleRow = $(rows[index]);
                //Get the Reason Dropdown selected value
                var selectedReasonKey = singleRow.find(":selected").val();
                var selectedReasonText = singleRow.find(":selected").text();
                var existingReasonText = $.trim(singleRow.find('td').eq(9).html());
                //If the selected value is not empty (is empty only when the text is "--Select--")
                if (selectedReasonKey != "") {
                    existingReasonText = decodeEntities(existingReasonText);
                    if (selectedReasonText != existingReasonText) {  //Add to the Array
                        //alert("existingReasonText : " + existingReasonText + "selectedReasonText : " + selectedReasonText);
                        selectedReasonKeyArr.push(selectedReasonKey);
                    }
                }
            }

            //Check if the Array length is more than 0 then display message
            if (selectedReasonKeyArr.length > 0) {
                // alert("Please save unsaved Data before Navigating to the next Page.");
                var existingErrMessage = $('#divNrpErrorMessage').text();
                if (existingErrMessage.indexOf("Please save unsaved Data before Navigating to the next Page.") == -1) {
                    var newErrorMessage = existingErrMessage + " Please save unsaved Data before Navigating to the next Page.";
                    $('#divNrpErrorMessage').text(newErrorMessage);
                }
                //Finding the first row of the selected page and staying on the same page by using the below extension method
                oTable.fnGetPageOfRow(rows[0]);
            }
            else {
                $('#divNrpErrorMessage').text('');
                $('#divNrpSuccessMessage').text('');
            }
        });
    });
```

In client side, i am able to do it easily by using the extension method `oTable.fnGetPageOfRow(rows[0]);`

***For Server side processing my code like below***

```
       [HttpPost, OutputCache(Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
        public JsonResult LoadNotReportingDataTable()
        {
            var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw").FirstOrDefault();
            var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
            var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();
            var sortColumn = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[" + Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]").FirstOrDefault() + "][name]").FirstOrDefault();
            var sortColumnDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]").FirstOrDefault();
            var search = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]").FirstOrDefault().ToLower();
            int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
            int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
            int totalRecord = 0;
            int filteredRecord = 0;

            var assetsNotReportingModelList = new List<AssetsNotReportingModel>();                                     
            var result = GetAssetsByNotReportingReasonWiseCountDts(15, "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "NR").ToList();
            assetsNotReportingModelList.AddRange(result);

            //Assign the totalrecord for jquery datatable - server side processing
            totalRecord = assetsNotReportingModelList != null ? assetsNotReportingModelList.Count() : totalRecord;
            var v = (from item in assetsNotReportingModelList select item);
            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDir))))
            {
                v = v.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir);
            }
            filteredRecord = v.ToList().Count();
            var data = pageSize == -1 ? v.ToList() : v.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();

            JsonResult json = Json(new
            {
                draw = draw,
                recordsFilterd = filteredRecord,
                recordsTotal = totalRecord,
                iTotalRecords = totalRecord,
                iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredRecord,
                data = data
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            json.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return json;
        }
```

***ServerSide Processing - Javascript code here***

```
var prestart = 0;
var prepaginationval = 1;

$(document).ready(function () {
    var isSuperUser = '@isUserSuperAdmin';
    var notReportingPaginationArr = [];
    var oTable = $('#tblnotreportingdetails').dataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "@Url.Action("LoadNotReportingDataTable", "Home")",
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json",
            "headers": headers,
            "beforeSend": function (xhr, opts) {
                //debugger;
                //if any changes available in the current  page(reason/remark) tnen get the current page number and assign to the global variable
                if (notReportingPaginationArr.length > 0) {
                    prepaginationval = $('#tblnotreportingdetails_wrapper').find('.dataTables_paginate').find('ul.pagination').find('li.active a').attr("data-dt-idx");
                    //alert('pervious page no : ' + prepaginationval);
                }
            },
            "data": function (d) {
                d.nrp = JSON.stringify(notReportingPaginationArr);
                d.prestart = prestart;
                return d;
            },
        },
        "dom": 'Bftrip',
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": '<i class="fa fa-search">&nbsp; </i>'
        },
        "paging": true,
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "pageLength": 7,
        "serverSide": true,
        "processing": true,
        "language": {
            "loadingRecords": "&nbsp;",
            'processing': "<i id='processingIcon' class='fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-2x'></i>"
        },
        "columns": [

            {
                "title": "Asset Code", "data": "Asset_ID", "name": "Asset_ID", "visible": true, "searchable": true, "sortable": true, "class": "text-left-align",
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    var oemkeycontrol = '<input type="hidden" name="OEM_Key" id="hdnOEM_Key" value="' + full.OEM_Key + '" />';
                    var assetidcontrol = '<input type="hidden" name="Asset_ID" id="hdnAsset_ID" value="' + data + '" />';
                    var companycodecontrol = '<input type="hidden" name="CompanyCode" id="hdnCompanyCode" value="' + full.CompanyCode + '" />';
                    var notreportingreasontypecontrol = '<input type="hidden" name="NotReportingReasonType" value="' + full.NotReportingReasonType + '" />';
                    var assetoverviewcontrol = full.IsForAssetOverview == "Y" ? '<a title="Click to view Asset Overview" style="cursor: pointer;font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;color:#3884c7 !important" data_toggle="tooltip" id="' + data
                                                                   + '" onclick=moveToAssetOverviewFromNotReporting("' + data + '","' + full.CompanyCode + '","' + full.OEM_Key + '","' + full.NotReportingReasonType + '")>' + data + '</a>'
                                                                   : '<a title="EMS Asset" data_toggle="tooltip" id="' + data + '" class="disabled">' + data + '</a>';
                    return oemkeycontrol + assetidcontrol + companycodecontrol + notreportingreasontypecontrol + assetoverviewcontrol;
                }
            },
            {
                "title": "Asset Description", "data": "Asset_Name", "name": "Asset_Name", "visible": true, "searchable": true, "sortable": true, "class": "text-left-align"
            },
            {
                "title": "IC", "data": "ICShortCode", "name": "ICShortCode", "visible": true, "searchable": true, "sortable": true, "class": "text-center"
            },
            {
                "title": "Job Code", "data": "Job_Code", "name": "Job_Code", "visible": true, "searchable": true, "sortable": true, "class": "text-left-align"
            },
            {
                "title": "Job Description", "data": "Job_Desc", "name": "Job_Desc", "visible": true, "searchable": true, "sortable": true, "class": "text-left-align"
            },
            {
                "title": "Last Reported Time", "data": "Date", "name": "Date", "visible": true, "searchable": true, "sortable": true, "class": "text-left-align"
            },
            {
                "title": "Days Not Reported", "data": "NotReportingAge", "name": "NotReportingAge", "visible": true, "searchable": true, "sortable": true, "class": "text-center",
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        var notreportingagecontrol = '<a title="Click to view History" style="cursor: pointer;font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;color:#3884c7 !important" data_toggle="tooltip" ' +
                        'id="ancNotReportingAge" onclick="displayNotReportingReasonHistoryPopUp(\'' + full.Asset_ID + '\',\'' + full.Asset_Name + '\',\'' + full.CompanyCode + '\',\'' + full.OEM_Key + '\');">' + data + '</a>';
                        return notreportingagecontrol;
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "title": "Days Not Reported with Current Reason", "data": "CurrentNotReportingReasonAge", "name": "CurrentNotReportingReasonAge", "visible": true, "searchable": true, "sortable": true, "class": "text-center"
            },
            {
                "title": "Reason", "data": "_ReasonKey", "name": "_ReasonKey", "visible": true, "searchable": false, "sortable": false, "className": "noExport",
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    var $select = $("<select class = 'form-control', style = 'font-size:11px;width: 150px;'></select>", { "id": "drpReason", "value": data });
                    var $defaultoption = $("<option></option>", { "text": "--Select--", "value": "" });
                    $select.append($defaultoption);
                    $.each(full.NotReportingReason, function (k, v) {
                        var $option = $("<option></option>", { "text": v.Text, "value": v.Value });
                        if (data == v.Value) { $option.attr("selected", "selected") }
                        $select.append($option);
                    });
                    return $select.prop("outerHTML");
                }
            },
            {
                "title": "_Reason", "data": "_Reason", "name": "_Reason", "visible": false, "searchable": true, "sortable": false, "class": "text-left-align"
            },
            {
                "title": "Reason Created By", "data": "ReasonCreatedBy", "name": "ReasonCreatedBy", "visible": true, "searchable": true, "sortable": true, "class": "text-left-align"
            },
            {
                "title": "Reason Updated By", "data": "ReasonUpdatedBy", "name": "ReasonUpdatedBy", "visible": true, "searchable": true, "sortable": true, "class": "text-left-align"
            },
            {
                "title": "Remarks", "data": "Remarks", "name": "Remark", "visible": true, "searchable": true, "sortable": true, "data-orderable": false, "class": "text-center",
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    var remarkcontrol = '<textarea id="txtRemarks" class="form-control" style="font-size:11px;width: 150px;" title="' + full.RemarkEnteredOnDate + '">' + data + '</textarea>';
                    return remarkcontrol;
                }
            },
            //{
            //    "data": "Remarks", "name": "Remarks", "visible": false, "searchable": false, "sortable": false, "class": "text-left-align"
            //},
            {
                "title": "Reason & Remark History", "data": "", "name": "Reason&RemarkHistory", "visible": true, "searchable": false, "sortable": false, "data-orderable":false, "class": "text-center noExport",
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    if (full._ReasonKey && full._ReasonKey != -1) {
                        return '<a class="btn btn-xs mybtn-info cursorpointer display-mode" onclick="displayNrReasonAndRemarkHistoryPopUp(\'' + full.Asset_ID + '\',\'' + full.Asset_Name + '\',\'' + full.CompanyCode + '\',\'' + full.OEM_Key + '\')" '
                               + 'data-title="Click to view Reason & Remarks History" title="Click to view Reason & Remarks History" data-toggle="tooltip">'
                               + '<i class="fa fa-history" title="Click to view Reason & Remarks History" style="padding:5px; font-size:17px;"></i></a>';
                    } else {
                        return '<a class="btn btn-xs mybtn-info cursorpointer display-mode" title="No Reason & Remarks History Available" data-toggle="tooltip" disabled>'
                               + '<i class="fa fa-history" title="No Reason & Remarks History Available" style="padding:5px; font-size:17px;"></i></a>';
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "title": "Source/OEM Provider", "data": "OEM_Provider", "name": "OEM_Provider", "visible": true, "searchable": true, "sortable": true, "class": "text-center"
            },
            {
                "title": "Location Details", "data": "", "searchable": false, "sortable": false, "class": "text-center noExport",
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<a class="cursorpointer mapmarkercolor dialog" id="btnMap" onclick="getAssetMap(this,\'' + full.Asset_ID + '\',\'' + full.Asset_Name + '\',\'' + full.CompanyCode + '\',\'' + full.OEM_Key + '\',\'Last\')" '
                            + 'data-toggle="tooltip" title="Last known location" name="' + full.Asset_Name + '" style="font-size:2.5em;color:deepskyblue;"> <span class="icon-Map-Marker"></span></a>';
                }
            }
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
                        {
                            "targets": 5,
                            render: function (data) {
                                if (data != null)
                                    return moment(data).format('DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss A');
                                else
                                    return '';
                            }
                        }
        ],           
        "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {               
        },
        "initComplete": function (settings, json) {                
        }
    });

    //Function to alert the user to save information on navigating to the next page through Pagination
    oTable.on('page.dt', function (e, oSettings) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selectedReasonKeyArr = [];
        notReportingPaginationArr.length = 0;
        //Getting the current page visible rows (10 rows/20 rows/50 rows/100 rows - default is 10 rows)
        var rows = $("#tblnotreportingdetails tbody tr");
        for (var index = 0; index < rows.length; index++) {
            //Getting each row
            var singleRow = $(rows[index]);
            //Get the Reason Dropdown selected value
            var selectedAssetId = singleRow.find("#hdnAsset_ID").val();
            var selectedCompanyCode = singleRow.find("#hdnCompanyCode").val();
            var selectedOemKey = singleRow.find("#hdnOEM_Key").val();
            var selectedReasonKey = singleRow.find(":selected").val();
            var selectedReasonText = singleRow.find(":selected").text();
            var selectedRemarkText = singleRow.find("#txtRemarks").text();
            var data = oTable.api().row(singleRow).data();
            var existingReasonText = $.trim(data["_Reason"]);
            //If the selected value is not empty (is empty only when the text is "--Select--")
            if (selectedReasonKey != "") {
                existingReasonText = decodeEntities(existingReasonText);
                if (selectedReasonText != existingReasonText) {  //Add to the Array
                    //alert("existingReasonText : " + existingReasonText + "selectedReasonText : " + selectedReasonText);
                    selectedReasonKeyArr.push(selectedReasonKey);
                    notReportingPaginationArr.push(
                        {
                            "Asset_ID": selectedAssetId,
                            "CompanyCode": selectedCompanyCode,
                            "OEM_Key": selectedOemKey,
                            "NewReasonKey": selectedReasonKey,
                            "NewReasonText": selectedReasonText,
                            "NewRemarkText": selectedRemarkText
                        });
                }
            }
        }

        //Check if the Array length is more than 0 then display message
        if (selectedReasonKeyArr.length > 0) {
            // alert("Please save unsaved Data before Navigating to the next Page.");
            var existingErrMessage = $('#divNrpErrorMessage').text();
            if (existingErrMessage.indexOf("Please save unsaved Data before Navigating to the next Page.") == -1) {
                var newErrorMessage = existingErrMessage + " Please save unsaved Data before Navigating to the next Page.";
                $('#divNrpErrorMessage').text(newErrorMessage);
            }
            debugger;
            var p = oTable.api().page.info();
            prestart = p.start > 6 ? (p.start - p.length) : p.start;
            oTable.api().draw(false);

            //var data = oTable.row(rows[0]).data();
            //Finding the first row of the selected page and staying on the same page by using the below extention method
            //oTable.fnGetPageOfRow(rows[0]);
            //oTable.row(rows[0]).data(data).draw(false);
            //var p = oTable.api().page.info();
            //oTable.fnClearTable();
            //for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            //    oTable.fnAddData($(rows[i]));
            //}
            //oTable.page(p.page).draw('page');

            //oTable.ajax.reload(null, false);

            //oTable.draw(false);

            //oTable.fnPageChange(0, true);

            //oTable.settings()[0].oFeatures.bServerSide = false;
            //oTable.settings()[0].ajax = false;
        }
        else {
            $('#divNrpErrorMessage').text('');
            $('#divNrpSuccessMessage').text('');
        }
    });            
});
```

But server side, how to do ?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the execution on your beforeSend method using xhr.abort();

You should do something like this.

```
 "ajax": {
        "url": "@Url.Action("LoadNotReportingDataTable", "Home")",
        "type": "POST",
        "datatype": "json",
        "headers": headers,
        "beforeSend": function (xhr, opts) {
            //debugger;
            //if any changes available in the current  page(reason/remark) tnen get the current page number and assign to the global variable
            if (notReportingPaginationArr.length > 0) {
                prepaginationval = $('#tblnotreportingdetails_wrapper').find('.dataTables_paginate').find('ul.pagination').find('li.active a').attr("data-dt-idx"); 
                xhr.abort(); //<------ This will prevent to call your API
                var rows = $("#tblnotreportingdetails tbody tr");
                oTable.fnGetPageOfRow(rows[0]);//<-- this hack will undo the page number highlight.
            }
        },
        "data": function (d) {
            d.nrp = JSON.stringify(notReportingPaginationArr);
            d.prestart = prestart;
            return d;
        },
    },
```

The answer below cold help you.
[Stop $.ajax on beforeSend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507079/stop-ajax-on-beforesend)

Comment: That's fine but it is creating another problem. The clickable page no is getting highlighted instead of previous one

Comment: I'm not site If I understand the other problem. Try add this code after xhr.abort(); oTable.fnGetPageOfRow(rows[0]);

Comment: If It does not solve your problem. Could tou provide a print pra this?

Comment: it's server side processing. oTable.fnGetPageOfRow(rows[0]); will not be executed

Comment: Is this event been fired after xhr.abort? oTable.on('page.dt

Comment: this is regarding serverside processing in jquery datatable

Comment: oTable.on('page.dt', function (e, oSettings) is a javascript event. Its not running on server side.

Comment: I update the answer with the sugestion I made on my first comment